# How to convert string to an int array using stoi() && substr()

Tags: c++

im triying to convert an string to an integer and save those numbers into an array, i tried like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int number[5];
    string input;
    //numbers
    cout << "type sonme numbers"<<endl;
    cin >> input;
    for(int i = 0 ; i<= 4; i++){
        number[i] = stoi(input.substr(i,i),0,10);
        cout << number[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

when i run it this error comes out:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
what():  stoi

Comment: what is the input?

Comment: A [range `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) over the string. Make sure that the character [is a digit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit#:~:text=int%20isdigit(%20int%20ch%20);,is%20not%20equal%20to%20EOF.). If it is, then subtract the character `'0'` from the digit character to get its integer value.

Comment: Are you trying to convert a string into just one integer, or a list of integers? It seems you might want each individual digit to be its own integer (e.g. typing 12345 gives an array with 1,2,3,4,5)? Is that what you want? Or are you looking for a list of multi-digit integers separated by some punctuation?

Comment: Typo? `substr(i,i)` -> `substr(i,1)`?

Comment: You could use the string to initialize an `istringstream istr( input )`, then just `istr >> number[i]` out of it. Or you could `cin >> number[i]` directly. Just saying, you're making this complicated. ;-)

Comment: Also note that `cin >> input;` will stop at the first whitespace.

Comment: @DevSolar: That works if the goal is to parse whitespace-separated numbers. My *guess* is they're trying to parse individual digits of a single contiguous integer, and thus `cin >> input;` is in fact correct; they wanted to pull the one logical integer, then parse each digit separately. But who knows?

Comment: @ShadowRanger Best to wait for clarity from OP before *guessing* an answer?

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Oh, right... but then it'd be *one* number. And accessing `stoi(input[i])` would be much easier... `substr(i,i)` just makes no sense... I don't get it either way. ;-)

Comment: @AdrianMole: I'm guessing at what their goal is. I'm 100% on the problem. They asked about the problem (the parsing error), which is 100% explainable without further clarity, which I consider answerable.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yeah - I got that part. But the question title suggests more clarity is needed before a meaningful answer can be provided.

Comment: @DevSolar: `stoi` doesn't work on individual `char` values last I checked, so `.substr` is needed to make the substrings. You could manually parse ASCII digits I guess, but then you'd be responsible for your own error-checking too. Unless performance is critical, I'd tend to favor `substr`+`stoi` just to minimize possible errors.

Comment: When you're debugging this kind of code it's always helpful to start out with a fixed string rather than prompting for input. And when you're asking other people for help that's even more important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first loop is asking for a substring beginning at index `0`, with length `0`, so you're passing an empty string to `stoi`. Even if you in fact provided valid inputs (a string of at least eight digits, so you could call `.substr(4, 4)` on it and get useful results), the first loop always tries to parse the empty string and dies. Don't do that.

It's unclear what the goal here is. If you meant to parse each digit independently, then what you wanted was:

```
number[i] = stoi(input.substr(i, 1), 0, 10);
```

which would parse out five sequential length one substrings.